# package exists with `sudo python`, but not when running `python`

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I'm provisioning a machine on AWS. When I set up this machine on the AWS public cloud (using a standard-issue Ubuntu AMI), I am successfully able to `sudo pip install -r REQUIREMENTS` all of the python packages I need—like Flask—in the system-wide python distribution:

```
[bash]$ python -c "import flask; print flask.__file__"
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.pyc
[bash]$ python -c "import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-20.2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

When I use the same `sudo pip install -r REQUIREMENTS` on a private Ubuntu AMI (that has undoubtedly been adapted to have "better security"), those packages appear to install just fine, but when I run python from the command line, I get an `ImportError`.

```
[bash]$ python -c "import flask; print flask.__file__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Interestingly, running the command with sudo yields the expected result that I get on the public AWS account:

```
[bash]$ sudo python -c "import flask; print flask.__file__"
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.pyc
```

`sys.path` is identical when running `python` and `sudo python` and both appear to have `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on file:

```
[bash]$ python -c "import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
[bash]$ sudo python -c "import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-20.2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Any suggestions here would be very welcome. I've never seen anything like this before and I'm having trouble figuring out what is different on this modified Ubuntu AMI that could be causing the issue.

Comment: That is very strange. Off the top of my head, there are three things to check: 1) Permissions on the files/directories of the flask installation. 2) Check the `pip` version, and make sure it matches your Python version. Do a `pip --version` and make sure it's the correct version (Python 2.7 or Python 3.x). 3) I assume there are other dependencies in your requirements file. Try a fresh environment and _only_ install flask (just to rule out the possibility of the other libs causing an issue).

Comment: @larsbutler It turns out that the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` directory had some permission problems. I will add a Q&A style response below to reveal the answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` directory did not have `a+r` access. As a result, we had to run a few commands to fix things:

```
# change permissions on the directories to read and execute, files to read
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7 -type d | xargs sudo chmod a+rx
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7 -type f | xargs sudo chmod a+r
```

This was a really bizarre problem and I hope that someone someday finds this useful (or, better yet, doesn't run into the problem in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Is `/usr/local/lib/` in your PATH? Check with `echo $PATH`. If not, add it by following this SA thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path